# Showing meta questions in the same manner as linked and related questions

Tags: feature-request, meta, related-questions, linked-questions

In the right column there are linked and related questions. I'm suggesting to add a third section: "Meta".

If a question on the main site is linked to by a question on meta, that meta question should show up in the meta section of the question on the main site.

We could also have this meta section on meta, since meta also is meta meta.

Comment: And what would be the *advantage* of adding such a feature?

Comment: @Cody, I find it interesting to know if a question is being discussed on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has its primary uses in linking a question on the site with any discussion about the question on the Meta site. This gives a simple way so that people on the main site realize that there *is* discussion about that specific question that may warrant their eyes to investigate.

However, this is really the only guaranteed pertinence, and half the time users are hesitant to link the question on the Meta site (usually because they don't want to point fingers). If it's also a serious discussion, there is often a comment on the post that provides a link to the Meta discussion, resulting in some level of redundancy.

My largest issue, though, is that many times a link on Meta will *not* be on discussion about the particular question that is linked. It could just be a reference as an example, and sometimes it's just quoting from something that happens to be on the main site. These instances are fairly common and do not serve a substantial benefit to browsers of the main site to view at within the context of the linked question.

So I don't see a lot of benefits, as there is one benefit it does serve but that benefit is easily handled by a comment.