# Can I link to my meta question from comments of cited or related questions?

Tags: discussion, meta, linked-questions

I asked a Meta Stack Exchange question which references one or more questions on normal Stack Exchange sites. I want to make sure that people who are interested are able to find it, but at the same time I don't want to create spam or to appear to be self-promoting.

Is it OK to link to my Meta question from the comments of the linked questions? From other related questions?

(See also "[Showing meta questions in the same manner as linked and related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98560/showing-meta-questions-in-the-same-manner-as-linked-and-related-questions)", which suggests making this partly automatic)

Comment: Comments are meant to indicate issues with the post and/or requests for clarification. In case of bug-reports (mathJax doesn't render, prettify is goofed up) I can imagine such links to be informational / useful but beyond that I don't see much value, or it must be for the occasional *this question is discussed on meta*. If your only goal is to bring more eyes to your meta contributions I would say this is not OK. Use the about me in your user profile to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a question is being discussed on the *per-site* meta -- for example, if somebody has started a discussion about closing, reopening, deleting, etc that question -- then it's a good practice to leave a comment linking to the discussion.  That's because the discussion *directly affects* the post in question.  It's a service to the owner of the post and interested observers, similar to leaving a comment pointing to a related question or a relevant resource.

I also sometimes see links to Meta.SE questions from related discussions on per-site metas -- an issue was raised locally, there's related discussion here, and people would reasonably want to know that.

I've never seen anybody complain about either of those categories of links.

What you're asking about, though, is another step removed.  Activity here on Meta.SE can't (generally) affect a specific question on another main site; people here aren't going to decide to reopen that question or delete that rant or whatever.  Those decisions belong to the individual communities.  Comments like what you're proposing amount to "hey FYI, you're being used as an example in this discussion".  I haven't seen much (if any) of that kind of comment, and I don't think it'll go over as well -- especially if you do it a lot.

Consider mentioning interesting Meta.SE posts in your site's chat room.  Or, if they are closely related to something your site is struggling with, raise it on your meta and link to the prior work here.